# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta indexada a una base de datos mySql creada con una app Winform en C#?

Tags: mysql, c#, windows-forms, indexeddb

Habiendo creado una base de datos con una app Winform en C# con `Table`, una serie de `Cells` y añadidos unos `Rows`;

¿Cómo puedo realizar una consulta indexada?

Comment: Es exactamente igual que si tuviera conexión

Comment: ¿Y sería posible recibir ejemplos para hacer esto en C# tiempo de ejecución como respuesta, sin toda la parte que corresponde a una DB conectada?

Comment: A parte en este foro, no he encontrado esta pregunta, con ni sin DB conectada. Nunca he manejado una DB MySql conectada, ni me interesa, y me resulta confuso, los ejemplos donde lo primero que se disponen es a conectar la DB. .. sin internet, sin red. Una DB de la app, lo mas simple. Esto me gustaria saber.

Comment: Yo creo que tienes una confusión, primero el término `indexar` se refiere a una acción de administración de una base de datos (la creación de índices) no tiene relación con C# ni con la conexión. Luego tu tienes tu aplicación y el motor de la base de datos, ambos deben comunicarse de alguna manera, generalmente se hace por socket y es irrelevante que tu tengas conexión a una red (LAN, PAN, WAN), porque siempre puedes contactarte contigo mismo usando "localhost" y si bien existen motores que alternativamente usan otros mecanismos me parece que MySQL no dispone de estos

Comment: Ok bro. Pues, quito lo que sobra. A ver si logro saber como hago esto. Gracias.

Comment: Luego C# y en especifico .net es una tecnología que lleva mucho tiempo y abarca un amplio abanico de otras tecnologías (WPF, WinForm, ASP.net, ASP MVC, etc) en cada uno el procedimiento es muy parecido, pero no igual. Entonces creo que debes enfocar la pregunta en un caso particular.

Comment: Si si, se lo que es indexar. .. de ahi mi pregunta para poder indexar en rumtime una DB de una app en MySql.

Comment: Ok. Pues ahi he etiquetado que se trataría de NetFramework / Winform. Gracias Yussef.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html

Comment: Primero: La redacción de la pregunta es muy vaga, además de tener varias preguntas, ninguna de las dos van con el formato del sitio. Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: Segundo: Si tratara de responder a la pregunta del título, el texto no ayuda. Quizás sea falta de conocimiento, pero hay muchas formas de crear una tabla desde C#, y si no mencionas cual es la que usas, hay muchas posibles respuestas. En líneas generales, la tabla la indexas lanzando una sentencia `create index` a la base de datos. Y, no, no puedes lanzar sentencias a la base de datos si no te has conectado a ella. No tienes por qué mantener la conexión, pero debes estar conectado para realizar cualquier trabajo en ella, al menos en MySQL y otras basses de datos relacionales.

Comment: De acuerdo. Edito pues de nuevo. Y entonces tendre que averiguar como logro que simule contectarse a un bucle interno de host de la maquina local, o buscar otro tipo de motor de base de datos de no ser posible esto ultimo. Gracias por la indicación spbre el  formato. Espero que ahora esté mejor.